# Acronym list extra-space beginning of page

Tags: glossaries

I'm using `glossaries` for managing my acronyms and also using the long style for displaying the list.

However I have noticed that when the change between letter/acronyms group is at the end of a page, then the next one is not started at top of the page but with the space between acronyms groups. So it is not vertically aligned.

In the mwe you can see that when changing from a to b, the beginning of second page has a space that is caused by the blank row between subgroups. Can it be avoided?

MWE:

acronyms.tex

```
\newacronym{AAA}{AAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA1}{AAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA2}{AAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA3}{AAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA4}{AAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA5}{AAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA6}{A}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA7}{AA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA8}{AA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{AA9}{AA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A10}{AA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A11}{AA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A12}{AA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A13}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A14}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A15}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A16}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A17}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A18}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A19}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A20}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A21}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A22}{bAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A23}{cAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A24}{cAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A25}{cAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A26}{cAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A27}{cAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A28}{cAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A29}{dAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A30}{dAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A31}{dAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A32}{dAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A33}{dAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A34}{dAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A35}{dAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A36}{eAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A37}{eAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A38}{eAA}{Acro} %
\newacronym{A39}{eAA}{Acro} %
```

acro.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{translator}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[acronym, toc, shortcuts, translate=babel]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand{\glspostdescription}{} % Remove page number
\loadglsentries[type=\acronymtype]{acronyms}


\begin{document}

\ac{AAA}\ac{AA1}\ac{AA2}\ac{AA3}\ac{AA4}\ac{AA5}\ac{AA6}\ac{AA7}\ac{AA8}\ac{AA9}\ac{A10}\ac{A11}\ac{A12}\ac{A13}\ac{A14}\ac{A15}\ac{A16}\ac{A17}\ac{A18}\ac{A19}\ac{A20}\ac{A21}\ac{A22}\ac{A23}\ac{A24}\ac{A25}
\ac{A26}\ac{A27}\ac{A28}\ac{A29}\ac{A20}\ac{A21}\ac{A22}\ac{A23}\ac{A24}\ac{A25}\ac{A26}\ac{A27}\ac{A28}\ac{A29}
\vspace{10cm}


\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long, nonumberlist]
\clearpage%


\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer was found in [this post][1]

  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56887/how-to-suppress-glsgroupskip-on-pagebreak-glossaries-package

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the O.P. found the answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56887/how-to-suppress-glsgroupskip-on-pagebreak-glossaries-package